# How to get returning ID in JPA after native query insert

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have the following code in JPA to return an auto generated ID after inserting using native query:

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("insert into .... returning ID", Long.class);
q.executeUpdate();
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
A result was returned when none was expected
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OK that was an easy one. I have just used q.getSingleResults() and it worked fine!

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery(sql);
BigInteger biid = (BigInteger) q.getSingleResult();
long id = biid.longValue();
```

Comment: In MySql this dosen work, you'll get next error.

java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().

Comment: In MySQL I used: 

    long lastId = ((BigInteger) entityManager.get().createNativeQuery("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()").getSingleResult()).longValue();

Comment: In MSSQL I got "org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet" on the line BigInteger biid = (BigInteger) q.getSingleResult();

Comment: it seems to really depend on the DB you are using. In my case, using Oracle, it getSingleResult throw a "could not extract ResultSet" too.

Comment: @mgueydan I've only tested it with postgres. are you returning the ID in the insert statement? I don't think its that straight forward in Oracle. In Oracle you need to save the id into a variable and then select it from dual. (insert into ... returning ID into :var; select :var from dual. But I'm not sure this works in JPA