# JPA native query insert returning id

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

I use the following code

```
EntityManager em.createNativeQuery("insert into users (name,surname) values (\"Test\",\"Test\") returning id").executeUpdate();
```

executeUpdate method return me 1 if insertion was success, but how can i get id of new user using the query above(my db is Postgres);

Comment: Why the heck do you use a native query for something that simple, and not using `em.persist(user)`?

Comment: it's an example, i have a big postgres query that can't be converted toHQL or something else

Comment: @JBNizet There are cases where you'd want to use native queries. I'll give you one, when you want to `INSERT INTO t () VALUES () ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `executeUpdate` you can use [`getSingleResult()`](https://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/Query/getSingleResult) to   get the returned `id` from Postgres.

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45166885/5296354)